# How to load a shortcut then EXE in one file

Tags: shortcuts, combine

I have two files, one is a shortcut, the second is a .exe. I need to load the .exe, then the shortcut one after the other, by just starting one executable.

Is there any way of doing this through a program or through windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a batch file. Create a file with the extension .bat. Then edit this file with a text editor and add your shortcut path and executable path:

```
"C:\path\to\shortcut.lnk"
"C:\path\to\executable.exe"
```

If you do not want to wait for the first program to finish before starting the second, then your batch file can contain:

```
start /B "" "C:\path\to\shortcut.lnk"
"C:\path\to\executable.exe"
```